# Django model field, alternative value return if null?

Tags: django

Is there a way to return a different set value for a django model field if that field has a null value?

I have users with profile images (image_url), for users who do not have one I'd like to return a default no avatar url, rather than 'None'.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Could you give us an example :-)

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Added one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to just add an extra property to the model:

```
@property
def image_url_with_default(self):
    return self.image_url or whatever_the_default_url_is
```

Answer (score 2):

as @paulo-scardine suggested, just add a condition when you want to actually use it - i.e in a template, or if it's bound to be used in multiple places, as a method/property of the model (as @remcogerlich) suggested.

```
@property
def avatar(self):
    return self.image_url or settings.DEFAULT_AVATAR_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) option on the URLField?

you could do someting like:

```
image_url = models.URLField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True,  default='http://misyte.com/default-image.jpg')
```

Haven't tested it... there's also an ImageField on django.. maybe you could check that too

Hope this helps

Comment: does default insert anything into the database?

Comment: well... URLField is stored as a varchar in the DB, but i dont know if it will bypass the URL Validator and store "anything".. if you give it a try let me know the results n_n

Comment: @itsquestiontime1: yes, this would store the default url into the database. not optimal (what if it changes?)

Comment: hmm rigth.. now I see it's silly to store the default value on DB... it would be nice to have a "null_value" or something like that as an option on django models :)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `__getattribute__` method, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291363/5425359). This has the advantage of not introducing an additional property (that you'll need to remember, or update any relevant references for):

```
class User(models.Model):
    ....
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'avatar' and not attr:
            return 'path/to/default/img'
        return attr
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh, my... URL entered by the user... Looks dangerous.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True, null=True)

    def avatar(self):
        if self.image: return self.image.url
        return '/path/to/default/avatar.png'
```

If you store the image at your side you can at least run something like "[nude](https://github.com/ParthGandhi/nude.py)" in order to analyze an image for nudity.

Comment: The url is a path on the CDN, no need to worry there.

Comment: In Django you can point MEDIA_URL to the CDN and forget about it - storing the CDN url in the database seems to violate DRY.